# Django - loaddata from JSON dump gives 'no such table' error

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I am trying to load a JSON dump of my Django Sqlite db into a fresh db, using `manage.py loaddata`. I am encountering the following `django.db.utils.OperationalError`, however:

```
Could not load foo.Bar(pk=1): no such table: foo_bar
```

The table is definitely present in the database, and all my migrations are applied, checked using `showmigrations`. So I am stumped as to what's going on. I would not be surprised if it's something simple, however. Would appreciate any suggestions.

**N.B**: The db I'm trying to load the data into is just an empty file. Might that be the issue? Do I need to create the relevant tables in that fresh db before loading into it from the fixture?

Comment: How do you export the fixture? How do you import the fixture? Please share the commands.

Comment: Sure, I just dump it with `python manage.py dumpdata foo --indent 4 --output foo/fixtures/foo.json`, load it with `python manage.py loaddata foo.json --database test.db`. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. May foo_bar be an unmanaged model?

Comment: You've identified the issue yourself. You need to create the reelevant tables in the new database (i.e., you need to run migrations on it) before you can run loaddata.

Comment: @solarissmoke Thanks. How exactly do I run migrations for a new, empty database, though? I guess by running `migrate --database test.db`? Won't that just run all the existing migrations for my app?

Comment: For sqlite, migrations will create the database. So if the database is empty, just delete it and then run `migrate`.

Comment: @solarissmoke Actually what I'm doing is a test for a situation where I might lose my original db, and some or all of my migration files. So I just want to load my JSON dump into a new, fresh db in the same folder (the project top level). Is there no way to just do that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean. You need a properly set up db (with correct schema/tables) before you can use loaddata to populate it. If you have somehow lost migrations (you should be using a version control system to ensure you don't...) then you will need to make new migrations and migrate the database before you can load data into it.

Comment: @solarissmoke Indeed all my migration files are checked in to my Git repo. I do periodic JSON dumps which I also check in - I think of these as backups. So are you saying that if I have no db file at my project top level directory and I run `migrate`, I'll get a fresh db with all the relevant tables, which I can then populate using `loaddata`? Apologies for any confusion.

Comment: Yes - if you have no DB file and run `migrate`, it will create a new one and set up the tables. You should then be able to run `loaddata`.

Comment: @solarissmoke Got it. Crystal clear now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are still in development, try to reset the database. Be aware that all your data will get lost. Create and dump some new data and check if you still get the same error.

Here is a script how to reset the database:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#deletes the sqlite3 database
rm db.sqlite3

#deletes migration files of your module(s)
# __init__.py needs to be recreated
rm -R your_module/migrations/*
touch your_module/migrations/__init__.py

# migrates changes and synchronizes the database
python manage.py makemigrations && python manage.py migrate
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial
python manage.py migrate --run-syncdb
```